# How to set this dynamic range in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

Here are 3 worksheets.

[image: button]

[image: report]

[image: day]

---

Case:

I want to sum the days for each person. The result is displayed on worksheet-report.

The days information is stored in worksheet-day. The day is not fixed. The range of the days is dynamic which should be according to

```
row: that person row in worksheet-day
column :Worksheets("button").Cells(1, 2 ) to Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 2)
```

---

For example :

```
Worksheets("button").Cells(1, 2 ) 'store 3

Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 2 )  'store 5
```

In column A of worksheet-report ,the sum of day of Peter ,Tom ,Mary should be calculated .The result should be displayed on column B correspondingly .

Then ,their sum of the days should be searched in worksheet-day and add up the total within the range (D:F 'because the value in worksheet("button"))

The result should be :

```
Peter: 2
Tom:   3
Mary:  3
```

Lastly,this result displayed on worksheet-report column B correspondingly .

---

Here is my code:

```
Sub gg()
row = Worksheets("report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Row2 = Worksheets("day").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Dim rng As Range  'the range for sum
Dim row999 As Integer 'store the selected row index

For k = 2 To Row2 'check and store appropriate row
    If Worksheets("report").Cells(1, k).Value = Worksheets("day").Cells(1, k).Value Then
        row999 = ActiveCell.row
    End If
Next k

rng = Range(Cells(Worksheets("button").Cells(1, 2), row999), Cells(Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 2), row999))

For j = 2 To row  'do the sum
    Worksheets("report").Cells(2, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
Next j
End Sub
```

---

I guess the rng is inaccurate here.

```
rng = Range(Cells(Worksheets("button").Cells(1, 2), row999), Cells(Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 2), row999))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that the names do not match.  Tom is uppercase on Report and lower case on day.  Mary has an extra space on the Day worksheet "mary ".

Try to use shorter variable names when possible so that you can read each line of code without having to scan back and forth with your eyes.

```
Sub ProcessDays()
    Dim day1 As Integer, day2 As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim name1 As String, name2 As String

    With Worksheets("button")
        day1 = .Cells(1, 2)
        day2 = .Cells(2, 2)
    End With

    With Worksheets("day")

        For i = 2 To Worksheets("report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For j = 2 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                name1 = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 1)))
                name2 = UCase(Trim(.Cells(j, 1)))

                If name1 = name2 Then

                    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(j, day1), .Cells(j, day2))

                    Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)

                End If
            Next
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter passed to Cells is the row, and the second parameter is the column.

You should also qualify which worksheet the range is on.

So your line saying:

```
rng = Range(Cells(Worksheets("button").Cells(1, 2), row999), Cells(Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 2), row999))
```

should say

```
rng = Worksheets("day").Range(Cells(row999, Worksheets("button").Cells(1, 2)), _
                              Cells(row999, Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 2)))
```

However, you have a lot of other errors in your code.  I believe what you want is:

```
Sub gg()
    Dim lastrowReport As Long
    Dim lastrowDay As Long
    Dim rowReport As Long
    Dim rowDay As Long
    lastrowReport = Worksheets("report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastrowDay = Worksheets("day").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Dim rng As Range  'the range for sum

    For rowReport = 2 To lastrowReport ' loop through each of the rows on the report
        For rowDay = 2 To lastrowDay   ' find the entry for this person on the days sheet
            If Worksheets("report").Cells(rowReport, 1).Value = Worksheets("day").Cells(rowDay, 1).Value Then
                set rng = Worksheets("day").Range(Worksheets("day").Cells(rowDay, Worksheets("button").Cells(1, 2)), _
                                                  Worksheets("day").Cells(rowDay, Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 2)))
                Worksheets("report").Cells(rowReport, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: @evabb - in your original code the value of row999 was never being set (because "peter"<>"john", and "tom"<>"alan", and "mary"<>"tom") so you were trying to access column 0, thus giving an error.

Comment: i directly copy your code .ERROR 91 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506(v=vs.60).aspx for the Rng

Comment: @evabb Sorry - (a) I forgot to say `set` and (b) I made the mistake of not specifying which sheet I was referring to.  Answer has been edited - please try again.

Comment: now ,the result only show the result of peter . Should i add one more nested loop to search the other name ?(tom, mary)

Comment: Did you replace the entire set of code?  I tried my code on a copy of your data and it worked nicely.  The `For rowReport = 2 To lastrowReport` loop is going through each of the people on the Report sheet.

Comment: Yes , it is still not working .Even i try lastrowReport = 4 . You may check my sample excel file  https://www.sendspace.com/file/9rsz7b

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not going to follow a link to a non-SE website.  I suggest you step through the code line by line.  It should go through the If statement in the inner loop 6 times, process Peter's details, then jump back to the outer loop.  Then it should go through the If statement 3 times, process Tom's details, then jump to the outer loop.  Then it should go through the If statement in the inner loop 7 times and process Mary's details, then jump to the outer loop, then stop.  If that's not what is happening, leave a comment telling me